# Testing a simple directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, directive, phone-number

I wrote this directive (which works fine) but I'm having trouble testing it :

```
module.exports = /*@ngInject*/ function($filter) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
            var phoneNumber;

        if (scope.country === 'US' && value.length >= 10) {
          phoneNumber = value.replace(/[ &()-.]+/g, '');
          ngModel.$setViewValue(phoneNumber);
          ngModel.$render();
        } else {
          phoneNumber = value;
        }
        return phoneNumber;
      });
    }
  };
};
```

and I'm basically at square 1 after reading 200 articles and failing :

```
var factory = require('./us-phone.directive.js');
describe('US Phone Number directive', function() {
  it('should remove dashes, parantheses, and spaces' , function() {
    var value = '(555)555-5555';
    var phoneNumber = '';

    phoneNumber.should.equal('5555555555');
  });
});
```

Comment: What are you tring to do? Where is the error?

Comment: The test is failing, sorry that wasn't more clear

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to do:

1. Create a test scope.
2. Compile your directive, else you can't test it.
3. You use ngModel.$parsers.push, so you need to trigger an event on your element which simulate interaction. You can trigger it with `triggerHandler('input')`.
4. You need to start the digest cycle manually.

   ```
   describe('myApp', function () {
     var element;
     beforeEach(function () {
       module('myApp');
     });

     it('should replace special characters', function () {
       element = angular.element('<input phone ng-model="value"/>');
       inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
         var scope = $rootScope.$new();
         scope.value = '(555)-55 5555';
         var compiled = $compile(element)(scope);
         compiled.val(scope.value);
         compiled.triggerHandler('input');
         scope.$digest();

         expect(scope.value).toBe('555555555');
       });
     });
   });
   ```

I create a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/trollr/q1vd1hqs/